# How to set mid in binary search?

Tags: c#, arrays, binary-search

I was working on this problem [**278 First Bad Version**](https://leetcode.com/problems/first-bad-version) on LeetCode. I have used binary search to get the element.

My way of getting middle index of an array `m = (start + end)/2` was causing issue in case of large array, closer to MAX_LIMIT of int. First, I thought of int range overflow issue but I am not sure because it worked with `end = MAX_LIMIT` and some `start < MAX_LIMIT` even though its going over int range.

I would like to understand how `m = start + (end - start)/2` is better than `m = (start + end)/2`

Code 1 works with input :

2147483647

98765432

But Code 1 fails with input:

2147483647

987654321

I think overflow issue should either happen in both cases or none of them.

**1. Code which Worked with `m = (start + end)/2` but fails for large array**

```
 public int FirstBadVersion(int n) {
        if(n == 1){
            return 1;
        }
        
        int s = 1;
        int e = n;
        int x = 0;
        while(s != e){
            x = (s+e)/2;
            if(IsBadVersion(x)){
                e = x;
            }
            else{
                s = x + 1;
            }
        }
        
        return s;
    }
```

**2. Code which worked with `m = start + (end - start)/2`**

```
public int FirstBadVersion(int n) {
        if(n == 1){
            return 1;
        }
        
        int s = 1;
        int e = n;
        int x= 0;
        while(s != e){
            // x = (s+e)/2;
            x = s + (e-s)/2;
            if(IsBadVersion(x)){
                e = x;
            }
            else{
                s =  x + 1;
            }
        }
        
        return e;
    }
```

Comment: What does "works with input" mean?

Comment: That's simple - try putting `checked {`,`}` around your `x` calculation (and pick better variable names). You will find that `1 + 2147483647` causes an overflow, but `1 + (2147483647 - 1)/2` does not. You could do `long` arithmetic instead: `(int)(((long)s + e)/2)` to fix it.

Comment: @NetMage I tested my code with those input on LeetCode. It worked for one but failed for another

Comment: After the overflow occurs, whether the search will succeed or not is pretty much a matter of luck. Your `x` is negative, and what happens depends on particular mid path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have integer overflow when computing

```
(a + b) / 2
```

when `(a + b) > int.MaxValue` the sum of `(a + b)` can't be represented  as **32 bit** integer (it requires **33** bits), and you have incorrect (often negative) result (when bit `33` is ignored) which you then divide by `2`.

I suggest working with `long` in order to be safe from *integer overflow*:

```
public int FirstBadVersion(int n) {
  // Special case: all versions starting from #1 failed
  if (IsBadVersion(1))
    return 1;

  // let use long in order to avoid integer overflow
  long correct = 1;
  long failed = n;

  // while we have unknown version between correct and failed 
  while (failed - correct > 1) {
    int middle = (low + high) / 2); // it safe now : adding two long values

    if (IsBadVersion(middle)) 
        failed = middle;
    else
        correct = middle;
  }

  return (int)failed;   
}
```

If using `long` is *cheating* and you want to stick to `int`, you can use the formula below, for `int a, b` we can put (note that we don't add big values `a` and `b` but their halves)

```
(a + b) / 2 == a / 2 + b / 2 + (a % 2 + b % 2) / 2
```

Please, note that your formula is *not universal*

```
(a + b) = a + (b - a) / 2;
```

it will work in the particular case of problem #278 where `a` and `b` are positive, but will fail in general casw, say when `a = 1_000_000_000, b = -2_000_000_000`.